# Pydev Mac OS 64bit Mavericks and Kepler

Tags: eclipse, macos, pydev

I am trying to install Pydev on Eclipse Kepler/Luna on A MacBook running Mavericks (64 bit) and Jdk 1.8 (also checked in the Eclipse Configuration tab).

Pydev still doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

There's a section at http://pydev.org/download.html dedicated to dealing with that on Mac OS which should solve your problems (see the "Note on Mac OS" there).

Alternatively, LiClipse (http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/) comes with everything bundled.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thank you for your answer and your great work on pydev. The section you mentions is about not having the jdk 1.7 which is not the problem I am experiencing. The only solution which worked is to get the zipped version from source forge and unzip it in the dropin folder.

Comment: Actually, the solution there is putting a way to point it to the proper interpreter (because Eclipse still gets an older version of the java vm even when you have a new one installed) -- it's really strange that getting a .zip solved it whereas installing with the update site didn't -- but it's good that it did work for you :)

Comment: Fabio I have double checked Eclipse is started by the Jdk 1.7 (and I tested it with a Jdk 1.8 as well). The fact that unzipping the plugins in the dropin folder solved it shows the problem is not the JDK.